# How to find the sum of this series using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

**x - x^2/fact(2) + x^3/fact(3) ... -x^6/fact(6)**

I tried various ways, even used nested 'for' loops, but I can't seem to figure out the code, any help?

Comment: just `1-exp(-x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this; `order` defines how many terms should be taken into account:

```
def taylor(x, order=3):
    x_n = x
    fact = 1
    sign = 1
    res = 0
    for n in range(2, order+2):
        res += sign * x_n/fact
        x_n *= x
        fact *= n
        sign = -sign
    return res
```

for comparison (because this is the same function):

```
from math import exp

def real_funtion(x):
    return 1-exp(-x)
```